# Validate Arabic Numbers in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have a form that contains a field for user to enter amount value of certain payment. This field is input of type number.

The validation rule in Laravel for this input is:

```
'amount' => 'required|numeric'
```

When I enter the amount in English as: `1500 =>` The validation passes and everything is OK.

But when I enter the amount in Arabic as: `١٥٠٠ =>` The validation fails with the following error message:

> "validation.numeric"

Should I validate this field manually or is there another solution to this problem?

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create your own validation type.

You can add something like this to your boot method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.

```
Validator::extend('arabic_numbers', function ($attributes, $value, $parameters, $validation) {
  $arabic_numbers = [
    '٥',
    '١',
    // add more
  ];

  $input = $value;
  if (!$input) {
    return false;
  }
  $chars = preg_split('//u', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  foreach ($chars as $char) {
    if (!in_array($char, $arabic_numbers)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
});
```

You can add to your existing rule, e.g. `required|arabic_numbers`.

Or use something like this:

```
$input = '١';
$validator = Validator::make([
    'user_input' => $input,
], [
    'user_input' => 'required|arabic_numbers'
];

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

Also you can use in many other ways for example in a custom request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'something' => 'required|arabic_numbers',
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I ended up with this: converting Arabic numbers to English numbers then applied the normal validator 'required|numeric'.