# Laravel Validation Not Working For Multi-byte Characters

Tags: php, laravel

I have an input where user enters his work shop code, and work shop code must be 10 digits. So in my validation I have :

```
$apply_data = $request->validate([
   'workshop_name' => 'required|string',
   'workshop_code' => 'required|string|digits:10',
]);
```

Now when user enters 1231231231 its ok. but if user enters ١٢٣١٢٣١٢٣١ (10 Arabic numbers instead of English numbers) Laravel will return following error

> work shop code must be 10 digits

I guess laravel is using `strlen` rather than `mb_strlen`, because workshop is actually 10 digits.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
Laravel is actually using strlen rather than mb_strlen
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/41ea7cc3bb898ff86505d3798d8acbb8992a0aad/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L414

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690793/validate-arabic-numbers-in-laravel-5

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/41ea7cc3bb898ff86505d3798d8acbb8992a0aad/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1401

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir its for size, digits is using strlen https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/41ea7cc3bb898ff86505d3798d8acbb8992a0aad/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L414

Comment: it seems like this particular validation rule is very ASCII biased, but you could try using `regex:\p{N}{10}` (taken from [the manual on unicode character properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)). The idea is to match 10 unicode characters that are (unicode) numbers. I'm not sure if it will work, it seems to work in https://regex101.com/ but not in https://www.phpliveregex.com/ so it's kind of a hit and miss

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you can achieve this by using the regex to determine the input is 10 unicode numbers like below:

```
$apply_data = $request->validate([
   'workshop_name' => 'required|string',
   'workshop_code' => [ 'required', 'string', 'regex:/^\p{N}{10}$/u' ],
], [ 
   'regex' => 'Workshop code must consist of 10 numbers'
]);
```

`\p{N}` means a unicode character having the property N (number)

Answer (score 0):

First of Laravel must fix their code in order to support multi-byte characters. but for now we can use size instead of digits

```
$apply_data = $request->validate([
   'workshop_name' => 'required|string',
   'workshop_code' => 'required|string|size:10',
]);
```

[laravel size validation uses mb_strlen()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/41ea7cc3bb898ff86505d3798d8acbb8992a0aad/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1401)